# no luck in rewriting url with query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My wordpress site runs a Download Monitor plugin (legacy version) that generates URLs with query strings such as:
`example.com/blog/download/?did=1` (The number is incremental)

I would like to Super Cache those pages using WP Super Cache plugin and it seems that it is only possible if the URLs don't contain query strings.

I think it would be best to rewrite:

```
example.com/blog/download/?did=1
```

to

```
example.com/blog/download/did/1
```

(I am not sure if I should append a slash at the end of the URL)

I referred to some examples from this site and the closest I got is the following rewrite rule but does not work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^did=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /download/did/%1? [NE,R]
```

Can someone point out what did I miss to get this rewrite working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That only rewrites the URI with the query string to one without. The wordpress plugin is probably not going to understand that. You need to internally rewrite it back:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /blog/download/?\?did=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /blog/download/did/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^blog/download/did/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog/download/?did=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Redirected fine but getting a 404 not found when reached the URL without query string (example.com/blog/download/did/1)